# How to automate the production of loops in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe of links to academic papers and identifying handles from a database called RePEc. It looks like this:

```
link <- c("http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1042957318300366", "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1042957318300664", "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1042957318300627", "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002205311830156X", "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1090951618303419", "http://hdl.handle.net/10.1093/jjfinec/nby006")
repec_id <- c("RePEc:eee:jfinin:v:38:y:2019:i:c:p:19-44", "RePEc:eee:jfinin:v:38:y:2019:i:c:p:1-10", "RePEc:eee:jfinin:v:38:y:2019:i:c:p:58-68", "RePEc:eee:jetheo:v:182:y:2019:i:c:p:329-359", "RePEc:eee:worbus:v:54:y:2019:i:4:p:372-386", "RePEc:oup:jfinec:v:17:y:2019:i:3:p:462-494")
df <- data.frame(repec_id, link, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I have written a loop that takes each of the links and downloads the file it leads to (or returns a warning/ error message if the link is broken). It looks like this:

```
urls <- df$link
output <- rep(NA, length(urls))
for (i in seq_along(urls)) {
  output[i] <- tryCatch(
    {download.file(urls[i], paste0('~/Desktop/Dataset/', basename(urls[i])))}, 
    error = function(e) {NA},
    warning = function(w) {NA}
  )
```

However, I don't actually want to download any files. I only want to know which entries return an `error` or `warning` (in this case, producing a `NA`). Does anyone know how I can modify my script so I don't actually download anything but I can figure out which ones are producing error/ warning messages?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Perhaps the [url.exists function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RCurl/versions/1.95-4.10/topics/url.exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple function that shows how you can turn an error into a `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on whether the url exists:

```
is.valid.url <- function(url)
{
  suppressWarnings(tryCatch(
    length(readLines(url, warn = FALSE)) > 0, 
    error = function(e) return(FALSE)
    ))
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!!